# How to make a html Project live if i have Godaddy domain details

Tags: html, eclipse

Hi everyOne it might be a wrong Question to ask here but i am very new in making any website live , i dont know the basic steps to make any html project which is created in Eclispe .

Please suggest a way , which i can follow !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to Godaddy, go to the control panel and from there try to find the file manager. You can upload your files there to the root of your website (The root is just like www.bob.com not a sub domain hello.bob.com).

Before you upload make sure your homepage is index.html.

I hope this helps!

Comment: hi @littleswany , my doamin is http://petsdon.com/ and inside my public-html folder i have uploaded my AptApp.html file , now how to move forward .

Comment: Sorry for the late response! You need to rename AptApp.html to index.html so that when you go to http://petsdon.com/ it shows that page if that is the one you want to be the homepage!

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your server to the domain ip.  If you have a server, put your files there, and then find out the dns.  usually 2 addresses, somethign like ns1.address.com & ns2.address.com

Then in godaddy update your dns to match your server.  you can try this video:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKBErrvGHaY